# Change a Nullable column to NOT NULL with Default Value

Tags: sql, sql-server, default-value, alter-table, alter-column

I came across an old table today with a datetime column called 'Created' which allows nulls.  Now, I'd want to change this so that it is NOT NULL, and also include a constraint to add in a default value (getdate()).

So far I've got the following script, which works fine provided that I've cleaned up all the nulls beforehand:

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.MyTable ALTER COLUMN Created DATETIME NOT NULL
```

Is there any way to also specify the default value as well on the ALTER statement?

Comment: do you want to fill all the already existing records with today's date?

Comment: Yep; that would suffice.

Answer (score 112, accepted):

I think you will need to do this as three separate statements.  I've been looking around and everything I've seen seems to suggest you can do it if you are *adding* a column, but not if you are altering one.

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.MyTable
ADD CONSTRAINT my_Con DEFAULT GETDATE() for created

UPDATE MyTable SET Created = GetDate() where Created IS NULL

ALTER TABLE dbo.MyTable 
ALTER COLUMN Created DATETIME NOT NULL
```

Comment: Has anyone else actually *tried* this?  I've found that the second statement fails due to null value in the table (despite the presence of a default value).  You need to insert a step between those two where you clean out the existing nulls.

Comment: Looks like someone edited the answer. It is now correct and complete.

Answer (score 13):

You may have to first update all the records that are null to the default value then use the alter table statement.

```
Update dbo.TableName
Set
Created="01/01/2000"
where Created is NULL
```

Answer (score 11):

you need to execute two queries:

**One - to add the default value to the column required**

> ALTER TABLE 'Table_Name` ADD DEFAULT 'value' FOR 'Column_Name'

i want add default value to Column IsDeleted as below:

> Example: ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Employees] ADD Default 0 for IsDeleted

**Two - to alter the column value nullable to not null**

> ALTER TABLE 'table_name' ALTER COLUMN 'column_name' 'data_type' NOT NULL

i want to make the column IsDeleted as  not null

> ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Employees] Alter Column IsDeleted BIT NOT NULL

Comment: Does not appear to work with SQL Server: the null values *already in* the table are not affected.

Answer (score 3):

If it's SQL Server, you can do it on the column properties within design view.

Try this:

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.TableName 
  ADD CONSTRAINT DF_TableName_ColumnName
    DEFAULT '01/01/2000' FOR ColumnName
```

Comment: This needs to be in script form so that it can be run as part of our automated release process.

Comment: Still no dice.  The constraint gets added; but it still barfs when it tries to convert the NULL to NOT NULL

Comment: Script to update all the nulls to set the value to your default then apply it? Sorry, ain't being much help!

Comment: I eliminated the statement to convert null to not null and the solution works.  Since there is a default value defined, all my new entries are getting my set default so I appear to have no risk for null values.  Just make sure your code never sets a null value in your update statements.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```sql
ALTER TABLE table_name ALTER COLUMN col_name data_type NOT NULL;
```